# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ELSE"

Tags: sql, oracle

I meet this problem.

```
 case room_rec.roomID
 37        when null
 38        then v_counter := v_counter
 39        else  v_counter := v_counter+1
 40       end as counter;
```

This error message shown

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
39/7     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ELSE" when expecting one of
         the following:
         . ( * @ % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
         <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
         like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset
         The symbol ";" was substituted for "ELSE" to continue.

40/6     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the
         following:
         * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
         <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
```

I wish to run the case wisely, but the error message pop out many times.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be:

```
v_counter := case when room_rec.roomID is null
             then v_counter
             else v_counter+1
             end;
```

Comment: LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
40/18    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "AS" when expecting one of the
         following:
         * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
         <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
         like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset
         The symbol "* was inserted before "AS" to continue.

Comment: I fixed it, check it.